# How To Get Total Count of Main Functions Having Same Constraints Under Their Own Sub-Functions?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on a project that needs to take a count of the total main functions having the same constraints under the sub-functions. However, it is posing to be more challenging than I have thought, and haven't been able to figure it out. Please help if possible!

Currently, this is the table given to me (with the main function column merged).

| Main Function | Sub Functions | Constraints |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | sub func 1a | Constr 1 |
| main func 1 | sub func 1b | Constr 1 |
|  | sub func 1c | Constr 2 |
| ------------- | ------------- | ----------- |
| main func 2 | sub func 2a | Constr 1 |
|  | sub func 2b |  |
| ------------- | ------------- | ----------- |
| main func 3 | sub func 3a | Constr 2 |

So what I did is add a new column to list individual main function/row since from what I learned is that merged cells are a no-no when working with formulas and I cannot edit the original table.

| Main Function | Sub Functions | Constraints | MFnc/Row |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | sub func 1a | Constr 1 | main func 1 |
| main func 1 | sub func 1b | Constr 1 | main func 1 |
|  | sub func 1c | Constr 2 | main func 1 |
| ------------- | ------------- | ----------- | ----------- |
| main func 2 | sub func 2a | Constr 1 | main func 2 |
|  | sub func 2b | Constr 3 | main func 2 |
| ------------- | ------------- | ----------- | ----------- |
| main func 3 | sub func 3a | Constr 2 | main func 3 |

But here, I am stuck on what to do next... and what I'm looking for in the output would be...

| Unique Constraints | # of Affected Main Function |
| --- | --- |
| Constr 1 | 2 |
| Constr 2 | 2 |
| Constr 3 | 1 |

Where -

- **Constr 1**: affected 2 Main Functions (main func 1 & main func 2)
- **Constr 2**: affected 2 Main Functions (main func 1 & main func 3)
- **Constr 3**: affected 1 Main Function (main func 2)

I've tried different methods with nested formulas but none came up correct or just simply hit errors. Thanks so much for helping with this... sorry again for requesting something that I'm sure is easy for others.

Comment: If you're using a version of Excel that supports Dynamic Arrays, look into `Unique`.  Then apply a `Countifs` to its result

Comment: So that's what I did at least for the Unique Constraints column: `=UNIQUE(C2:C6)` to get the dynamic list of constraints. For the # of affected main function, I would need to somehow reference the unique constraints to take the counts. For that, just missing the criteria part `=COUNTIFS(UNIQUE(D2:D6),...)` where the criteria would have to use the unique constraints as part of the equal condition. Sorry... really bad at this.

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out on the condition after watching a youtube video :D. Ty for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

So figured this out using Chris's suggestion... (Columns are listed from A-C)

To get unique constraints: `=UNIQUE(FILTER(C2:C6,C2:C6<>"",""))` to get...

| Unique Constraints |
| --- |
| constr 1 |
| constr 2 |
| constr 3 |

Then to get the count of main functions where each constraint occurred in - `=COUNTIF(UNIQUE(C1:D6),[Unique Constraints]A1#)` to get the count of each main function, resulting in...

| Unique Constraints | # of Affected Main Function |
| --- | --- |
| constr 1 | 2 |
| constr 2 | 2 |
| constr 3 | 1 |

Thank you again for help making it clear!